# Trouble with order of reading next line with Scanner

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner, inputstream

I am doing some basic java program using 'Scanner'. I read Integer, Double and String.

I have some issues with using scanner for String with other scanners like int and double.

**Declaration part:**

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i2;
    double d2;
    String s2;
```

**Order#1:**

```
    i2 = scan.nextInt();
    d2 = scan.nextDouble();
    s2 = scan.nextLine();
```

**Result:**
Compiler waits to get input for i2 and d2 but not waiting for input for s2. It execute line after `s2 = scan.nextLine();` instantly. When i debug, s2 is empty.

**Order#2:**

```
    i2 = scan.nextInt();
    s2 = scan.nextLine();
    d2 = scan.nextDouble();
```

**Result:**
Compiler waits to get input for i2 and **s2** this time. When i give input `hello` it throws an error.

```
1
hello
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:18)
```

**Order#3:**

```
    s2 = scan.nextLine();
    i2 = scan.nextInt();
    d2 = scan.nextDouble();
```

**Result:**
works fine !!

So why order is playing role here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in execution, with *change in orders*, is due to the fact that ***new-line*** is **not** consumed by `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, `next()` or `nextFoo()` methods.

Therefore, whenever you place a call to `nextLine()` after any of those methods, it consumes that ***newline***, and **virtually skips over that statement**.

The fix is simple, don't use `nextFoo()` methods before `nextLine()`. Try :-

```
i2 = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
d2 = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
s2 = scan.nextLine();
```

Or else, you could consume the ***new-line*** by

```
i2 = scan.nextInt();
d2 = scan.nextDouble();
scan.nextLine(); //---> Add this before the nextLine() call
s2 = scan.nextLine();
```

**Order#3** works fine, as `nextLine()` is the first statement, and therefore, there are **no** *left-over* characters to consume.

Related: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `next()` instead `nextLine()` to read String.

Comment: `scan.next()` takes only first word, but i want to take complete line.
For ex: ''Hello World'', `scan.next()`  - takes only  'Hello'.

Comment: You can use BufferedReader instead Scanner. So all problems will be solved)

Comment: I can use 'FooReader' as well, but i am curious to know what it causes.

Comment: @user252514 check my answer.